# Read Response failed on c# application

Tags: c#, http, https

I have c# application which is installed as windows service. Dtabase used is sqlite. Open source Tiny HTTP server is used for url communication with clients.
HTTP and HTTPS service is used inside the application to communicate with clients. there are 10 clients which connects to server using http and method and port for example 8084. And one client which uses HTTPS with port example 8444. All these client applications are developed in flex application.
Now i have a url calling folder/tree/200(calls by https) and folder/tree/690 (calls by http) which reads data from sqlite and return the response as xml. Code as below,

```
public string Tree()
{
    try
    {
        string langstr = "";
        if (Request.QueryString["lang"] != null && 
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["lang"].Value))
        {
            langstr = Request.QueryString["lang"].Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ThingzDatabase db = SessionDatabase;
            langstr = db.DefaultLanguage;
            db = null;
        }

        folderTree = new FolderTree(Convert.ToInt32(Id), true, 
                            SessionDatabase, langstr);
        XmlDocument doc = folderTree.XML;

        Response.ContentType = ContentType.Xml;
        langstr = null;

        return doc.InnerXml;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Get folder tree failed, reason:" + e.Message;
    }
}
```

And when i checked in fiddler i was receiving an exception called read response failed when https calls folder/tree/200 . return xml is a big data .What i am doing wrong here. Please help me to resolve it.

Regards
Sangeetha

Comment: I think you may need to clarify exactly what Fiddler sees. Any HTTP response code? Any data? Where does it say "Read response failed"?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Timestamp: 10:18:52.685

[Fiddler] The socket connection to (domainname) failed. <br />ErrorCode: 10061. <br />No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.